# Finding the max value in and Array

Tags: java, arrays

I have looked at other questions but not exactly the issue that I am facing here,
This is the current code that I have

```
public class Qn3 {
    public static void displayHighestMark(String[] names,int[] marks, int count)
    {
        int mark = 0;
        int currentArrayPosition;
       for(int i=0;i <= names.length;i++)
       {

          if(mark <= marks[i])
              mark = marks[i];
          currentArrayPosition  = i;
       }
       System.out.println(name[i]+" with marks "+mark);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] names = new String[]{"jack","hello","A","b","c","d"};// = new String[];

         int[] marks = new int[]{1,2,3,8,5,6};
        displayHighestMark(names,marks, 45);
    }

}
```

So basically I am trying to find the highest mark in the marks array. But I am getting expection of ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Oh boy, don't you wish there where higher-order programming in Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 for(int i=0;i <= names.length;i++)
```

should be

```
 for(int i=0;i < names.length;i++)
```

Because you are trying to get `marks` for index which is outside the range you got `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Array index starts from 0, so when you do looping and lookup always need to look for `<` instead of `<=`

Please read this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

**EDIT:**

```
if(mark <= marks[i])
{
              mark = marks[i];
          currentArrayPosition  = i;
}
```

Comment: tks for that pls see my editied question I am trying to display the corresponding value in the name array. I meant to say if the highest value in the array is in the index 4 then I want to display the array value of the name array of the same index.

Comment: @noobprogrammer: Your edit not reflecting removal of = from the for loop. I would suggest first make that change and run your program.

Comment: Oh, no, no I want to leave it there so the future users will know the whole purpose of this thread, that is why I left it there, but I ran it with the solution you gave works perfect, but still facing the first comment problem, tks

Comment: Ok, got it. So, what is the results you are getting now?

Comment: The solution I am getting is ,"e with marks 8", from the above edit in my original posting the 8 is in the middle of the array but, e, is in the last index of the name but I want to align these tks

Comment: Add curly braces for if block, see my answer EDIT.

Comment: Glad it helped. Good luck. Enjoy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Change loop to

```
for(int i=0;i < names.length;i++)
```

Moreover, why do you need `count` variable as one of method params. You are not using it.

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
for(int i=0;i <= names.length;i++)
```

to

```
for(int i=0;i < names.length;i++)
```

because in you are trying to access an item outside of the array when variable `i` is equal to `names.length` because the array's index is beginning from `0` to `array's length - 1`